# image src get 404 error with vuejs

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm new to vue.js, and trying to render a list of images using `v-for` directive. Instead, I get `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I'm using the [template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) generated by [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli).

The webpack url-loader  should change the url of the image corresponding to `item.src` to some `[name].[ext]?[hash]` format, but it simply leave them alone (actually the result url is `http://localhost:8080/assets/computer.jpg` ).

And here's my code:

```html
<template>
  <h2 class="ui header">
  <div class="content">
   Recent Research
   <div class="sub header">
    recent research issue
   </div>
  </div>
 </h2>
  <div v-for="item in items" class="ui three column centered grid">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="ui centered medium image" :src="item.src" />
      <h3 class="ui header">{{item.text}}</h3>
      <p class="teal meta">{{item.extra}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export
  default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [{
            src: '../assets/computer.jpg',
            text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
            extra: 'with Google'
          }, {
            src: '../assets/computer.jpg',
            text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
            extra: 'with Google'
          }, {
            src: '../assets/computer.jpg',
            text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
            extra: 'with Google'
          }, {
            src: '../assets/computer.jpg',
            text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
            extra: 'with Google'
          }, {
            src: '../assets/computer.jpg',
            text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
            extra: 'with Google'
          }, {
            src: '../assets/computer.jpg',
            text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
            extra: 'with Google'
          },

        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And the related webpack config.

```js
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/static'),
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue'
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
      loader: 'url',
      query: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
      }
    }]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel'
    }
  }
  /*
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  }
  */
}
```

Comment: If 404 status is returned form the images then check the images url requested and change it accordingly if it is wrong, be aware that item.src should be relative to your domain not your current .js file

Comment: The request url is correct. There may be something wrong with the webpack's bonding process. The webpack url-loader just leave the url corresponding to item.src alone (actually the result url is some `http://localhost:8080/assets/computer.jpg` ) , while it should change the url to some `[name].[ext]?[hash]` format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are passing a string to the 'src' field of your items array, no way webpack can tell if that string is a resource.

I'd suggest you try to change it to something like:

```
 items: [{
    src: require('../assets/computer.jpg'),
    text: 'fundamentals of search engine',
    extra: 'with Google'
  }, {    
....
```

That way the output may be processed by webpack.

Comment: If you landed on this page from Google like me: If you started the project with vue-cli, and are using Airbnb ESLint, it will nag about global-require. Just turn that off, this seems to be the [official solution](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126) no matter how dirty it may feel.